# How do you put multiple things under a limit?

Tags: math-mode

I'm reading about inverse limits, and the notation sometimes requires some sort of index or set over which to take the inverse limit. It looks something like this:

[image]

How would I correctly TeX that? I tried something like             `{\lim_{\longleftarrow}}_{H\in\mathscr{F}}`
but the arrow and the set are side by side, not one over the other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no need for `\substack` in this case: there are the `\varinjlim` and `\varprojlim` macros taking care of both direct and inverse limits, putting a subscript now results in the behaviour you're looking for (and everyone is mimicking using `\substack`).

Comment: Thanks Pieter, I didn't know such macros existed. Just was I was looking for.

Comment: @Pieter: You're right. Use `\usepackage{mathtools}` and then `\underset{i}{\varinjlim}` for inverse limit, and `\underset{H\in\mathscr{F}}{\varprojlim}` for direct limit (the latter requires `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` as well).

Comment: @Werner He needs `\varprojlim` when reproducing the examples, inverse limits are also known as projective limits. And why use `\underset`? Just `\varprojlim_i` will do fine, even in text style where it is appropriate for the limit to be on the right.

Comment: @Pieter: You're right, again...

Answer (score 3):

Without going into too much font detail, you can use the `\mathop{<stuff>}` command to make an operator of almost anything in mathmode. For example, here's a small modification to your initial try:

```
\mathop{\lim_{\longleftarrow}}_{i}G/H_i \approx
  \mathop{\lim_{\longleftarrow}}_{H\in\mathcal{F}}G/H
```

[image: Mathop to define mathematical operators with limits]

However, you may also be interested in stacking items on top of one another using `\stackrel{<top>}{<bottom>}`:

```
\lim_{\stackrel{\longleftarrow}{i}}G/H_i \approx
  \lim_{\stackrel{\longleftarrow}{H\in\mathcal{F}}}G/H
```

[image: Stacking limits using \stackrel]

Consider browsing through [Herbert Voß' mathmode document](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf). It is filled with typesetting information in mathmode.

Comment: @yunone: It does modify the fontsize slightly for the `<upper>` part. In this case `\longleftarrow`; that's why you see it being slightly shorter.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `\substack` of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

```
\lim_{\substack{\longleftarrow\\H\in\mathscr{F}}}
```

[image: substack example]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[ \lim_{\xleftarrow[i]{}}G/H_i \approx
   \lim_{\xleftarrow[\mathclap{H\in\mathcal{F}}]{}}G/H \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new operator using `\DeclareMathOperator` of the `amsmath` package as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\ulalim}{\underleftarrow\lim}

\begin{document}

\[\ulalim_{i}G/H_{i}\approx\smashoperator{\ulalim_{H\in\mathcal{F}}}G/H\]

\end{document}
```

The resulting output is:

[image]

Note the usage of `\smashoperator` to remove redundant white space between the operator and the operand on the right-hand side of the equation.

Comment: OK, in this specific case, you actually don't need to define a new operator since there is already one as pointed out by @Pieter.