# LaTeX adjusting \sum limits

Tags: math-operators

Is  there a way to show `\sum` limits partially in inline mode and partially in display mode?
I want to write:

```
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} [...]
\end{equation}
```

but this way the lower limit is too wide, and I don't like it. So I was hoping to write something like this:

```
\begin{equation}
\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\nolimits_{n} [...]
\end{equation}
```

to write the index n on the right side of the sum symbol, while the limits of the summation remain above and below.

Of course it doesn't work, LaTeX is pissed because there is a double subscript. Anyone knows if it's possible to do what I want to?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In this instance a better approach would be to use [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)'s `\mathclap`, which provides a centred overlap in math mode. The centred overlap implies a zero-width box containing stuff that overlaps on the left and right:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \\
  B &= \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}} f(x) \\
  C &= \sum_{\mathclap{n=-\infty}}^{+\infty} f(x) \\
  D &= \sum_{\substack{n={}\\-\infty}}^{+\infty} f(x) \\
  E &= \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathop{}_{\mkern-5mu n} f(x)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Sure `mathtools` also loads [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), but both these provide excellent tools in terms of typesetting mathematical content (and otherwise).

To add multiple things under a math operator (like `\sum`), see [How do you put multiple things under a limit?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26123/5764), which suggests `\substack` (as I've done in the last horrible visual).

Comment: If you asked me, I vote for option no. 2.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for something like point E., but with \prod, not \sum. When I tried copying using \mathop{}_{\mkern-5mu n} it did not look so good. How would you do it with prod?

Comment: I know it's an old answer but I put in my two cents nonetheless: the last version can be IMO better achieved by using `amsmath`'s own `\sideset` macro: `\sideset{}{_n}\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}`.