# Reduce horizontal space around sum with a big subscript?

Tags: amsmath, subscripts

What’s a good way to reduce the horizontal space around this big sigma? Ideally, I’d like to be able to tell LaTeX to always ignore the width of a subscript by default.

This example compiles with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

  \[\text{Pr}[x\oplus e\in D_x\,\wedge\, T]\leq \sum_{\substack{x\in C, \\ e\text{ satisfying }T \\\text{ where }x\oplus e\in D_x}}\text{Pr}[\text{we pick }x\text{ and }e]\]

\end{document}
```

And it generates this:
[image: an equation with a large amount of horizontal space around a summation sign with a wide subscript at the bottom]

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx,  Possible duplicate: [LaTeX adjusting `\sum` limits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89447)

Comment: Thank you so much! It looks like `mathclap` is what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\mathclap` command from the `\mathtools` package. If I compile this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \[\text{Pr}[x\oplus e\in D_x\,\wedge\, T]\leq
    \sum_{\mathclap{\substack{x\in C, \\ e\text{ satisfying }T
          \\\text{ where }x\oplus e\in D_x}}}\text{Pr}[\text{we pick
    }x\text{ and }e]\]
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility with the `\smashoperator` command, also defined by `mathtools`. I took the liberty to simplify a bit your code.

*Unrelated*: you don't have to load `amsmath` when you load `mathtools`, as the latter does it for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

  \[ \Pr[x\oplus e\in D_x\,\wedge\, T] \leq
    \smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{x\in C, \\ e\text{ satisfying }T
          \\\text{ where }x\oplus e\in D_x}}}\Pr [\text{we pick }x\text{ and }e]\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, thank you! Is that `\Pr` command loaded by `mathtools` or is it just available without loading any packages?

Comment: Not sure. I suppose it's defined by (a recent version of) `mathtools`, because I first coded with `\DeclareMathOperator{\Pr}{Pr}` and the log file answered it was already defined.